# Node ID is not appearing

Tags: views, nodes, 8

I am working on creating a view based on nid in Drupal 8.  I cannot find node id or nid listed - I see Entity id. I am trying to set up a contextual filter so only certain node fields (node type B) will show up when node type B's relationship field matches the node alias of node type A.
(I am looking at https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004, but the terminology is different for Drupal 8.)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out nid in Drupal 8 is now listed as ID - and it is listed liked this: 
Title - ID and Category - content.  It appears on the view as Content: ID. I put this in Fields and made it hidden.  I added a relationship to my other content type.  Then for contextual filter I used the Content:ID with the relationship. Under When filter is not available, I picked Provide default value: Content ID from URL. And then the view worked.